# CSS - Pyramid type of Text -

Tags: html, css

**Question:**  CSS. How do you get a Pyramid style of your Text using CSS? I mean not -text-center- Look a the Letters. Each Row has different padding.

[image: text]

I know using Padding left and Right You can get this :
[image]

```
padding-left: 30%;
padding-right: 30%;
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean

`text-align: center;`

```
p {
  text-align: center;
}
```

text is `text-align: left;` by default.

Here is a jsFiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/x58nejLL/

The rows do not have different padding. - it may appear that way.

Comment: No. I mean not center. Look at the letters. The style isn't determined by the length of words.. its using different padding for each row.

Comment: I didn't downvote you. But I will - not spend any more time with you. : )

Comment: @Nancy Nope. I did not. If I though your question was not valuable - I would vote it down and I would not add an answer. As you can see, I spent time trying to help you instead. There are many many many people looking at these posts and downvoting or upvoting them... not just the people here trying to help you. If you could shift your attitude a bit, I think you would be much more successful in your journey to learn web development. If you'd ever like to get an overview: https://www.codementor.io/sheriffderek

Answer (score 1):

This is the problem that [css shapes](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-shapes/) was being designed to solve. Unfortunately, we are a long way from having good implementations in browsers right now. As far as I know, the only approach is the hacky one of preceding the text with a stack of left and right floated elements.

Like this:

```css
article { line-height:20px; width:400px;  text-align:center; }
article > p { margin:0; }
article > div::before { float:left; clear:left; }
article > div::after { float:right; clear:right; }
article > div::before, article > div::after { content:'\A0'; }
article > div:nth-of-type(1)::before, article > div:nth-of-type(1)::after {
  width:55px;
} 
article > div:nth-of-type(2)::before, article > div:nth-of-type(2)::after {
  width:15px;
} 
article > div:nth-of-type(3)::before, article > div:nth-of-type(3)::after {
  width:30px;
}
```

```html
<article><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
<p>
Mark Zuckerberg likes his privacy, but he’s in an increasingly public battle with a would-be neighbor in Palo Alto, Calif., that threatens to expose details of his personal life and conduct.
</p>
</article>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's a static string, you could use 
 to break it down your self into proper lengths with a little bit of trial and error. You could even try viewport units to scale the text uniformly with screen size.

```css
p {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do  <br> eiusmodtempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.  <br>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation  <br>ullamco laborisnisiut aliquip ex  <br>ea commodo consequat.</p>
```

If the text is dynamic, you can run it through a loop and insert `<br>` after counting character